# Passar valores entre diretivas

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives, angularjs-scope

estou começando com angular e tenho uma dúvida. Tenho o seguinte cenário:
Criei uma diretiva com responsabilidade de mostrar mensagem na tela. Abaixo o código dela.

mensagem.js

```
"use strict";

angular.module("layout")
.directive('mensagem', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: '/Marcenaria/Scripts/App/Directive/Layout/mensagem.html',
        scope:{
            msgSucesso: '@',
            msgError: '@',
            msgInfo: '@'
        }
    }
});
```

mensagem.html

```
<div ng-if="msgSucesso" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4>    <i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> Sucesso!</h4>
    {{msgSucesso}}
</div>
<div ng-if="msgError" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4>    <i class="icon fa fa-warning"></i> Atenção!</h4>
    {{msgError}}
</div>
<div ng-if="msgInfo" class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4><i class="icon fa fa-info"></i> Informativo!</h4>
    {{msgInfo}}
</div>
```

Chamada da diretiva

```
 <mensagem msgError="{{msgError}}" msgSucesso="{{msgSucesso}}" msgInfo="{{msgInfo}}"></mensagem>
```

A dúvida é a seguinte, quando atualizo o msgError, por exemplo, essa informação não é atualizada dentro da diretiva mensagem e por isso não imprime a mensagem na tela, como resolvo ?

Comment: altere `@` por `=`

Comment: @FelippeTadeu, na verdade sua dica ajudou sim, mas precisei mudar o nome dos atributos da diretiva mensagem de msgError para error, com isso, acredito que estava com problema na hora de recuperar o valor do atributo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver o problema foi necessário alterar os @'s por = e alterar o nome dos atributos na diretiva mensagem, pois os nomes com camel case estavam dando problema.

```
"use strict";

angular.module("layout")
.directive('mensagem', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: '/Marcenaria/Scripts/App/Directive/Layout/mensagem.html',
        scope:{
            sucesso: '=',
            error: '=',
            info: '='
        }
    }
});
```

Chamada:

```
<mensagem error="{{msgError}}" sucesso="{{msgSucesso}}" info="{{msgInfo}}"></mensagem>
```